# Django ORM count group by issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    referrer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='referral_made')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, related_name='referral_received')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I need to group by the number of referrals for each **recipient**

This query works:

```
Referral.objects.values('recipient_id').annotate(total_referral=Count('recipient_id')).order_by('-total_referral')
```

and the output is

> [{'total_referral': 5, 'recipient_id': 929}, {'total_referral': 1,
>   'recipient_id': 143}]

The problem is that I need query objects for later use

If I remove the ".values('recipient_id')" I get separated records and not grouped.

```
Referral.objects.annotate(total_referral=Count('recipient_id')).order_by('-total_referral')
```

> [Referral: Referral object, Referral: Referral object, Referral:
>   Referral object, Referral: Referral object, Referral: Referral
>   object, Referral: Referral object]

I have made a lot of search and tested some answers but can't manage to get the results as Query objects

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of queryset objects do you need? `Referral` queryset objects, or `Profile` queryset objects?

Comment: Also, what version of Django ORM are you on?

Comment: `Referral` queryset only

Edit: I'm using Django 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve what you're trying to do using [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). Since you've used the `related_name` on the `recipient` key, let's suppose you start with the following queryset:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.prefetch_related('referral_received').all()
```

when you loop over each object in this queryset, the referrals received by that profile will be available (without any additional queries, since we've used `prefetch_related` above), like so:

```
groups = []
for each_profile in profiles:
    group_qs = each_profile.referral_received.all()
    groups.append({
        "recipient_id": each_profile.id,
        "total_referral": len(group_qs), 
        "queryset": group_qs,
    })
```

Note that if you don't use `prefetch_related`, then a separate query will be fired inside each loop iteration, and that will end up costing you a fair bit of I/O wait time, depending on the number of profiles.

Even though this approach eschews database-layer grouping in favor of grouping in python, the good news is that you're still able to do this using just a single database query.

Comment: Your solution works!   

After getting the count, here is what I have done:  

`a = [
    {'total_referral': 1, 'recipient_id': 143},
    {'total_referral': 5, 'recipient_id': 929}
]`

`for item in sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['total_referral'], reverse=True):
    print(item)`

and then I can sort from the highest to lowest.

Thank you!